# Need help setting up the inLanguage Schema for JSON-LD

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-ld

Google structured data testing tool keeps telling me that I am missing a schema for inLanguage

I have tried using this code

```
{
            "@type:":"PropertyValue",
            "inLanguage":"English"
            },
```

But it doesn't seem to be working on google structured testing tool. Any idea on how I can set this up?

Comment: Please include (→ [edit]) a minimal example that gives this warning.

Comment: @unor is correct, but have you read the documentation and seen this example: `"inLanguage": {"@type": "Language","name": "English","alternateName": "en"}` ?